# Java Applet is not running in a browser

Tags: java, security, applet

I am trying to run my applet in a browser, chrome/IE but I get the following message:

```
Your security settings have blocked a local application from running
```

Due to Oracle, changing security level in java control panel from high to medium will solve the issue, but it does not. I have even tried the low level, and custom level too enabling all applications to run without any prompt. I have also changed the advanced setting to allow unsigned applets to run. 
It does not work in any way.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any popup blocker? If yes please disable it and check!

Comment: No I do not have any pop up blocked and the ones built into the browser are disabled.

Comment: Are you testing it from a raw HTML file off the local file system, or from a local server?   I'd recommend to try the latter.  Are the classes in a Jar?  Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Just added for later viewers, I sovled this by enable Active-X in `Custom level...` option.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

1. Go to IE
2. Tools -> Internet Options
3. Go to the Advanced Tab
4. Under Java(Sun) Select the check box saying **'Use JRE ... for applet' (requires restart)**
5. Select Apply/Ok. Restart IE and try loading the applet again.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make sure that the applet is signed by a valid cert, and it is not a self-signed cert. Or if you just want to bypass the warning, you can add the domain address to Exception Site List.

Java Control Panel -> Security tab -> Exception Site List

and also you may also try to add the website to the Trusted Zone in your IE if you are sure that the website is safe. In Trusted Zone, there are fewer restrictions to block you from running applet and running the out-of-date ActiveX.